# Conditional parameter in jQuery function initialization?

Tags: php, jquery, json, initialization, conditional-statements

I'm using James Smith's excellent [tokenized input](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) plugin for a search box of sorts.  (PHP backend.)  I'm trying to prepopulate the input but only some of the time - for example, if the user has passed my URL a parameter.

Normal initialization:

```
$("#tokenized").tokenInput("http://www.my.url/index.php", {
theme: "facebook",
});
```

As desired, this starts me with a blank box and everything's good.

Using the nifty prePopulate paramater:

```
$("#tokenized").tokenInput("http://www.my.url/index.php", {
theme: "facebook",
prePopulate: [<?php echo json_encode($initialValue); ?>]
});
```

$initialValue is an array with 'id' and 'name'.  This also works great when it's set to something.  But that's my problem - only some of the time will it be set.  I've tried sending it a zero-element array as well as one with empty values.  Setting the array to null produces the expected uncaught exception.  The box refuses to not prepopulate if it's one of these - creating an entry for 'undefined' or '{space}'.  I want it to be empty, as the first example above.

How can I tell my page to only prepopulate if my initial value is set?  Can I do some sort of if() condition inline to the initialization?

Also, jQuery beginner here - as above, still using 'php echo' to get my value across.  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: just a notice, in the first example remove the trailing `,` as it will choke IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` is perfectly fine. Try this:

```
$("#tokenized").tokenInput("http://www.my.url/index.php", {
theme: "facebook"
<?php if($initialValue){ ?>, prePopulate: [<?php echo json_encode($initialValue); ?>]<?php } ?>
});
```

It only adds the `prePopulate` parameter if `initialValue` is set.